# Scroll detecting the 50% position of a <div> in the browser window

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the hidden div to 'slideDown' when it gets vertically in the middle of the browser window. But the div 'slideDown' as soon as I scroll the page with any distance.

Any clue?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#laptop_container').hide();

       $(window).scroll(function(){
       var distance =$('#laptop_container').offset().top;
       var halfbrowserHeight = $(window).height()/2;  

               if(distance = halfbrowserHeight){
               $('#laptop_container').slideDown(800);
           }
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you have place wrong condition in if statement

Comment: your code worked as I wanted only on my PC 27" monitor when the browser is full screen. but when I reduced its size, it worked very early so when the <div> get into the view area of the browser it was already visible.

Comment: I also tried it on iPad ... same thing

Comment: make halfbrowserHeight  globle and change the halfbrowserHeight  value within $(document).resize(function(){});

Comment: didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one to detect half of the window size scroll amount**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var halfbrowserHeight = $(window).height() / 2;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var distance = $(window).scrollTop();


        if (distance >= halfbrowserHeight) {
           alert('50%')
        }
    });
});
```